# Como fazer um loop ("FOR" ou "WHILE" ou "DO WHILE") em uma linha no VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Como consigo fazer um *loop* de uma linha usando VB.NET? Em outras linguagens consigo fazê-lo sem nenhum problema como nos exemplos abaixo:

> coloquei como exemplo somente para o `for` mas em todas as linguagens tanto `while` quanto `do while` também serviriam igualmente

```java
// Java
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) System.out.print(i + ", ");
// -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

[Teste em Java](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/ofg)

```cs
// CSharp
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) Console.Write(i + ", ");
// -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

[Teste em C#](http://rextester.com/DHAG69906)

```js
// Javascript
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) console.log(i + ", ");
// -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

[Teste em JavaScript](https://jsbin.com/zeyifa/edit?html,console)

```php
// PHP
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) echo $i.", ";
// -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

[Teste em PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e42c2e1eb18bea3117678e7ffd25265b8f206299)

```vb
// VB.net
???
// -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

**Edit**

Conforme o @Maniero disse, fui forçado a fazer o teste em todas as linguagens que listei, e os resultados estão logo abaixo das mesmas. Não estão erradas como ele diz.

Comment: Todos os loops vão de 0 a 9 e você descreve resultados de 1 a 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá para escrever de várias formas, uma delas seria:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 9 : Console.WriteLine(i & ", ") : Next
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/n71O5B). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HDNeCV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/CountComma.vb).

O resultado das outras linguagens está errado.

Comment: Eu tenho ciência dessa forma mas a questão é escrever em uma só linha e não em 3. Além disso os exemplos que coloquei de outras linguagens são apenas pra demostrar o foco da questão e não se estão certos

Comment: Se você demonstra algo errado, não pode reclamar de obter resposta errada.